# The best way to fetch and render a collection for a given object_id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I am trying to implement a simple app which is able to get a collection for a given `object_id`.
The `GET response` from the server looks like this:

```
[
    {object_id: 1, text: "msg1"}, 
    {object_id: 1, text: "msg2"}, 
    {object_id: 1, text: "msg3"},
    .......
]
```

My goal is:
 **render a collection when the user choose an `object_id`**.

The starting point of my code is the following:

```
this.options = {object_id: 1};
myView = new NeView(_.extend( {el:this.$("#myView")} , this.options));
```

My question is:
*** What is the best way:

1) to set the `object_id value` in the `MyModel` in order to

2) trigger the `fetch` in MyCollection and then

3) trigger the `render` function in `myView`?*** or to active my goal?

---

P.S:

My basic code looks like this:

```
// My View
define([
    "js/collections/myCollection",
    "js/models/myFeed"
], function (myCollection, MyModel) {
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {

            var myModel = new MyModel();

            _.bindAll(this, "render");

            myModel.set({
                object_id: this.options.object_id
            }); // here I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'set'
        }
    });

    return MyView;
});
```

---

```
// MyCollection
define([
    "js/models/myModel"
], function (MyModel) {

    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url: function () {
            return "http://localhost/movies/" + myModel.get("object_id");
        }
    });

    return new MyCollection
});
```

---

```
//MyModel
define([
], function () {

    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });

    return MyModel
});
```

Comment: may i suggest simple script loader such as script.js(https://github.com/ded/script.js) it is developed by Dustin Diaz a engineer from twitter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few, if not fundamentally things wrong with your basic understanding of Backbone's internals.

First off, define your default model idAttribute, this is what identifies your key you lookup a model with in a collection

```
//MyModel
define([
], function () {

    var MyModel = Backbone.MyModel.extend({
        idAttribute: 'object_id'
    });

    return MyModel
});
```

in your collection, there is no need to define your URL in the way you defined it, there are two things you need to change, first is to define the default model for your collection and second is to just stick with the base url for your collection

```
// MyCollection
define([
    "js/models/myModel"
], function (MyModel) {

    var MyCollection = Backbone.MyCollection.extend({
        model: MyModel, // add this
        url: function () {
            return "http://localhost/movies
        }
    });

    return MyCollection // don't create a new collection, just return the object
});
```

and then your view could be something along these lines, but is certainly not limited to this way of implementing

```
// My View
define([
    "js/collections/myCollection",
    "js/models/myFeed"
], function (MyCollection, MyModel) {
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new MyCollection();
            this.collection.on('add', this.onAddOne, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.onAddAll, this);
        },

        onAddAll: function (collection, options)
        {
            collection.each(function (model, index) {
                that.onAddOne(model, collection);
            });
        },

        onAddOne: function (model, collection, options)
        {
            // render out an individual model here, either using another Backbone view or plain text
            this.$el.append('<li>' + model.get('text') + '</li>');
        }

    });

    return MyView;
});
```

**Take it easy and go step by step**

I would strongly recommend taking a closer look at the exhaustive list of tutorials on the Backbone.js github wiki: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites ... try to understand the basics of Backbone before adding the additional complexity of require.js

Comment: Thanks for your time. Just one question: in which way the url is made? Actually I need an url like this `"http://localhost/movies/"+object_id+"/messages"`

Comment: as Backbone revolves around a RESTful approach, you have to look at your URL's as endpoints: /movies with method GET fetches all movies, /movies with POST creates a movie, /movies/id PUT modifies a movie, /movies/id DELETE deletes a movie. Read about how a URL gets constructed here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url

Comment: You mean that I have to change the server part in order to:  `"/documents/7/notes", would have this URL: "/documents/7/notes/101"`?

Comment: the url you specify there means get note with id 101 for document 7. in this case you would most likely want nested collections, which is also explained in the backbone documentation.