# How to trigger the fetch method and how to set the url

Tags: backbone.js

I'am redesigning my backbone application based on the answer of @20100 to this question [The best way to fetch and render a collection for a given object_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632527/the-best-way-to-fetch-and-render-a-collection-for-a-given-object-id/10632912#comment13783029_10632912).

Please read the comment on the code because I think is more clear, and my question looks better in smaller sizes.

---

```
// My View
define([
    "js/collections/myCollection",
    "js/models/myFeed"
], function (MyCollection, MyModel) {
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new MyCollection();
            this.collection.on('add', this.onAddOne, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.onAddAll, this);

            // when I make myView = new MyView(_.extend( {el:this.$("#myView")} , this.options));
            // myView.render is not called
            // in order to trigger the render function I make the following… but probably there is a better way … 
            var that = this;
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function () {
                    that.render();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    return MyView;
});
```

---

```
// MyCollection
define([
    "js/models/myModel"
], function (MyModel) {

    var MyCollection = Backbone.MyCollection.extend({
        model: MyModel, // add this
        url: function () {
            var url = "http://localhost/movies";

            return url; 
           // if I look to the GET request the url is without idAttribute
           // how can I attach the idAttribute to this url?
           // should bb takes care of this?

        }
    });

    return MyCollection;
});
```

---

```
//MyModel
define([
], function () {

    var MyModel = Backbone.MyModel.extend({
        idAttribute: 'object_id'
    });

    return MyModel
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two paths you want to explore

**Pre-populate your collection with your model data**

In your example you're already doing this, but you're fetching a collection, the collection URL is `http://localhost/movies`, if you want an individual model take a look at the next point

**Fetch each individual model only when you need it**

In the assumption that you're trying to get an ID on a collection that is not pre-populated and are loading 1 model at a time, you will have to approach this a bit in a custom way by adding a method to your collection somewhat similarly to this

```
getOrFetch: function(id, options) 
{
    var model;
    if (this.get(id)) 
    {
        model = this.get(id);
    } 
    else 
    {
      model = new this.model({
        id: id
      });
      this.add(model);
      model.fetch(options);
    }
    return model;
}
```

or add the function as `Backbone.Collection.prototype.getOrFetch` so you can use it on every Backbone Collection if you need it.